# AWS API gateway mapping model for two dimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am new to aws api gateway and I have deployed my application to aws api gateway and now I have two dimension array of media and for this is define a mapping template on api gateway but when I generate SDK after deploying then SDK did't generated the correct code for two dimensional array of media below is my example response and model that I define on gateway

**Response**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "5824d546-3f16-11e9-a005-3ca9f421c370",
        "full_name": "Satxcdfield",
        "username": "gustin16579",
        "is_private": false,
        "picture": "/staging4/users/k1irambzupload-image1546361823.jpg",
        "post_count": 1034,
        "box_count": 8,
        "follow_status": "",
        "media": [
            [
                {
                    "medium": "/staging4/users/k1irambzupload-image1546361823.jpg",
                    "height": 320,
                    "width": 180
                },
                {
                    "medium": "/staging4/users/k1irambzupload-image1546361823.jpg",
                    "height": 301,
                    "width": 180
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "medium": "/staging4/users/k1irambzupload-image1546361823.jpg",
                    "height": 320,
                    "width": 180
                },
                {
                    "medium": "/staging4/users/k1irambzupload-image1546361823.jpg",
                    "height": 240,
                    "width": 180
                }

            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**Model**

```
    {
  "type" : "object",
  "required" : [ "data" ],
  "properties" : {
    "data" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "full_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "username" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "is_private" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "picture" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "post_count" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "box_count" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "follow_status" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "media" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "array",
              "$ref":"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/v9ad25xv/models/GenericMedia"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total_friends" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

when I generate SDK then aws-api-gateway generate not correct for media.
I don't know that where I am doing mistake because I following AWS documentation for mapping template.